# "Connection is not secure" error in all the stackexchange.com pages

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stackexchange.com, ssl

In the [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) and in the all sub pages, I'm receiving the **Connection Is Not Secure** error.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Not secure error in SE]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your mixed content warning. I think it may be something on your end.